# Traefik for container with host network mode => Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

compose that declares a traefik reverse-proxy container :

```
reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
```

And a plex service :

```
plex:
    image: linuxserver/plex
    container_name: plex
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.plex.rule=Host(`plex.baptiste-arnaud.fr`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.plex.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.plex.loadbalancer.server.port=32400"
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - VERSION=docker
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/hdd1/plex/library:/config
      - /home/pi/hdd1/plex/tvshows:/tv
      - /home/pi/hdd1/plex/movies:/movies
    restart: unless-stopped
```

It uses the `host network` mode. I try to request `plex.baptiste-arnaud.fr` and it gives me a "Bad gateway". I have other services that work well. Can it work when a container is started with the host network?

Comment: Probably not, since host networking disconnects almost all of the standard Docker network setup; you can't do things like make inter-container calls by host name.  Especially if you're already got a proxy setup, can you use normal bridged networking?

Comment: Ok thank you @DavidMaze :) you can answer the question I'll validate